# Store who updated Django Model from admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a use case where data is only inserted and updated from django admin. Now, I have multiple users who have access to django admin page. I want to be able to store who exactly updated or created a record in django admin page.

Ideally, I want to add a separate column to an existing model.

`models.py`

```py
class Links(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = model.ForeignKey(UserModel)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = model.ForeignKey(UserModel)
```

Comment: If you end up wanting a full record of the record history, this package is fantastic: https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [**`.save_model(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) to set the `.updated_by` and `.created_by` fields, depending on whether `change` is `True` or `False`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class LinkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.updated_by = request.user
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Links, LinkAdmin)
```

If you need this for a large number of models, you can make a mixin, and then use that for all sorts of models:

```
class CreateUpdateUserAdminMixin:
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.updated_by = request.user
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

and then use the mixin with:

```
class LinkAdmin(CreateUpdateUserAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class OtherModelAdmin(CreateUpdateUserAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Links, LinkAdmin)
admin.site.register(OtherModel, OtherModelAdmin)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Link` instead of <s>`Links`</s>.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: How can I prevent this field from showing up in Django admin form?

Comment: @DebdutGoswami: set `editable=False` in the model fields for `created_by` and `updated_by`.